# How to programatically add a pseudo field to views and display the field value based on value of other field?

Tags: 7, views, entities

I need to add a field to view and display the value of that field depending on the value of other fields already present.

The pseudo field i need to add is not connected with any database table.

Comment: You could add a empty text field in the view. In on the preprocess of the view change the content of that field to be whatever you want. Or within the tpl file for that blank text field

Comment: If Leigh's suggestion doesn't work, there are a couple of views calc sort of modules. Or you could do it with jQuery.. It depends on whether or not you want your site to work without JS though. Doing it in PHP is harder but better; Doing it with JS is easier and more customisable.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the preprocess hook approach noted in the comments, you may want to use:

- Computed Field Module https://www.drupal.org/project/computed_field
- Views PHP Module https://www.drupal.org/project/views_php